# Creating polygon from lines, using the lines' attributes?

Tags: arcgis-10.3, fields-attributes, polygon-creation, dwg

I'm trying to transform lines into polygons with the attributes. The lines are from a dwg file. I tried to use "feature to polygons" but doesn't preserve the attribute. I tries to transform lines to points and than use them in the "feature to polygons"... still doesn't preserve the attributes.

[image]

Comment: If lines have different attribute values should they be concateneted?

Comment: Are the attributes stored as annotations?

Comment: Try converting the lines to single part features first using the [Multipart to Singlepart](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/multipart-to-singlepart.htm) tool.  When running this tool also disable the Z and M environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Exporteren naar shapefile en vervolgens naar featureclass?

In Table of contents -> Rechtermuisknip op polyline -> Data -> Export Data

en kiezen voor shapefile

---

(Machine translated)

Export to shapefile and then to feature class?

In Table of contents -> Right mouse click on polyline -> Data -> Export Data

and opt for shapefile

[image]